# How to access key and value from this dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, line

Here is a snippet of function code in Python:

```
def restart_lab_server(aws_client):

    response = aws_client.describe_instances()
    ###print(response)
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            # This sample print will output entire Dictionary object

            # This will print will output the value of the Dictionary key 'InstanceId'
            try:
                print(instance["Tags"])
            except:
                print("This instance does not have any tags.")
                print("Next Entry.")


    return 0
```

The output that I am getting this the following:

```
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'EC2-Nessus-AmazonLinux2'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'LCE Server'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Windows-2019-xxxxx'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'SecurityCenter-Lab-5.19.1'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Nessus-Target-Lab'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Nessus-Agent-Lab'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'NNM-Lab'}]
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'WindowsInstance'}]
This instance does not have any tags.
Next Entry.
[{'Key': 'CfStackId', 'Value': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:581987831513:stack/Nessus-Thomas-101-2/41d38410-5729-11ed-a52f-127af16651f7'}, {'Key': 'aws:cloudformation:stack-id', 'Value': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:581987831513:stack/Nessus-Thomas-101-2/41d38410-5729-11ed-a52f-127af16651f7'}, **{'Key': 'NessusScanner', 'Value': 'TRUE'},** {'Key': 'aws:cloudformation:logical-id', 'Value': 'NessusEC2Instance'}, {'Key': 'aws:cloudformation:stack-name', 'Value': 'Nessus-Thomas-101-2'}]
```

My main interest is to get "{'Key': 'NessusScanner', 'Value': 'TRUE'},"

I can't seem to extract this or not sure how to. I am not sure if I need to use a linescanner or something else.

I'm trying to restart all Nessus scanners in my and figured using key and value Nessus scanner True.

Please note, I'm using

```
describe_instances()
```

I have tried creating another for loop but keep getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer or workaround:

```html
def restart_lab_server(aws_client):

    response = aws_client.describe_instances()
    ###print(response)
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            try:
                x = instance["Tags"]
                for y in x:
                    print(y["Value"])

            except:
                print("This instance does not have any tags. Next Entry.")


    return 0
```